# How can I render different static apps in one nodejs app on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a nodejs express app to be deployed on heroku. It has 2 static front end apps that are to be rendered depending on the domain names. I used the express middleware vhost to dynamically load either of the 2 front end apps into the nodejs back end app depending on the domain the user enters into the url. The setup works very fine on my localhost, but the app crashes after pushing to heroku server.

Part of my server.js is setup as shown below:

```
const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const adminAppMiddleware = express.static(__dirname + '/../dist/admin');
const clientAppMiddleware = express.static(__dirname + '/../dist/client');
const vhost = require('vhost')
const history = require('connect-history-api-fallback'
app.use(vhost("myMainDomain.com", clientAppMiddleware));
app.use(vhost("admin.myMainDomain.com", adminAppMiddleware))
app.use(history({
  verbose: true,
  disableDotRule: true
}))
app.use(vhost("myMainDomain.com", clientAppMiddleware));
app.use(vhost("admin.myMainDomain.com", adminAppMiddleware))

app.listen(port)
})
```

Please can someone tell me how I can set this up so the app can run on heroku server?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I only needed to append "www." before the domain names in the server.js.